# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite strange internal redirect to domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a very strange issue with apache 2.4 since a while.

If I enable mod_rewrite and I go to a page that cannot be found then apache does a very weird internal redirect. The redirect is linked to one of my domains, but I don't understand from where is this coming.

What I did is the following:

- installed http://de.apachehaus.com/downloads/httpd-2.4.23-x64-vc14.zip
- I am using Windows 10
- the target directory is empty, there is no .htaccess or anything

For simplicity I've added these to the http.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:/Empty"
    ServerName projects.test
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

LogLevel debug rewrite:trace1
```

Now, here is the weird thing coming. If I request a unexisting page, eg: http://projects.test/test I get Internal Server Error.

A trace4 logging in error.log:

```
[Fri Sep 09 17:53:57.325193 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1116] child.c(399): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:443 using AcceptFilter data
[Fri Sep 09 17:53:57.325693 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1148] child.c(399): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:80 using AcceptFilter data
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(393): [client ::1:62560] Headers received from client:
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Host: localhost
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Connection: keep-alive
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Cache-Control: max-age=0
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   DNT: 1
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843332 2016] [http:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] http_request.c(396): [client ::1:62560]   Cookie: Phpstorm-f6f7591a=a1280346-7ebc-47e4-a371-0046f15ed62f
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:62560] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:62560] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [core:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client ::1:62560] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /test
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Empty/test -> Empty/test
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'Empty/test'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Empty/test -> Empty/test
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'Empty/test'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/test' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/test' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] rewrite 'Empty/test' -> '/interpid.eu/index.php'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] trying to replace prefix D:/ with /interpid.eu/
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] trying to replace context docroot D:/Empty with context prefix 
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] internal redirect with /interpid.eu/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:62560] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:62560] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [core:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client ::1:62560] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /interpid.eu/index.php
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] add path info postfix: D:/Empty/interpid.eu -> D:/Empty/interpid.eu/index.php
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Empty/interpid.eu/index.php -> Empty/interpid.eu/index.php
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'Empty/interpid.eu/index.php'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] add path info postfix: D:/Empty/interpid.eu -> D:/Empty/interpid.eu/index.php
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Empty/interpid.eu/index.php -> Empty/interpid.eu/index.php
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'Empty/interpid.eu/index.php'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/interpid.eu' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/interpid.eu' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] rewrite 'Empty/interpid.eu/index.php' -> '/interpid.eu/index.php'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] trying to replace prefix D:/ with /interpid.eu/
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] trying to replace context docroot D:/Empty with context prefix 
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.844334 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea5cc58/initial/redir#1] [perdir D:/] internal redirect with /interpid.eu/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

I can't figure out from where is this redirect done with the **/interpid.eu/index.php** domain??? It has probably something with my PC... but no idea what.

```
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'Empty/test'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/test' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] RewriteCond: input='D:/Empty/test' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] rewrite 'Empty/test' -> '/interpid.eu/index.php'
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] trying to replace prefix D:/ with /interpid.eu/
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] trying to replace context docroot D:/Empty with context prefix 
[Fri Sep 09 17:54:01.843833 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22932:tid 1072] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:62560] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1f54cf16858][rid#1f54ea562a0/initial] [perdir D:/] internal redirect with /interpid.eu/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, damn. I've had an .htaccess file on the "D:/.htaccess" with this content...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /interpid.eu/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /interpid.eu/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still, I thought that only the DocumentRoot "d:/Empty" will be taken into consideration for the .htaccess file.

Comment: It is definitely reading `D:/.htaccess`. Do you have another `DocumentRoot` set somewhere in Apache/vhost config?

Comment: No, I will investigate it next days, cause I never expected that D:/.htaccess will be read. The vhost DocumentRoot was set to D:/Empty

In httpd.conf 
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"

So, I got at least the cause, but it's still weird.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The .htaccess file is looked for upwards all the way to the root folder, not the document_root.